# After click js print button another button not working

Tags: javascript

When I click a js print button and back then another button not working.

After refresh all working fine.

```
function printDiv(divName) {
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;

}
```

Comment: Gonna need to see more code, like where `printDiv()` is being called

Comment: Works like expected in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0w6pzja8/2/

Comment: Dynamically Generated elements buttons don't work. So use 'on' attribute of jquery. It'll solve your problem.

Comment: @ChethanKulkarni thanks